# What is the least amount of steps to zero an array?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

We have an array of $n \times m$ of non-negative integers.

What we can do is, choose $a$ columns and $b$ rows, and then substract 1 from each cell that is in the junction of any columns of $a$ and any rows of $b$.

For example:
from this
$$
\begin{array}{}
2 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 2\\
\end{array}
$$
by choosing columns $1, 3$ and rows $1, 3$ you can get
$$
\begin{array}{}
\mathbf 1 & 1 & \mathbf 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
\mathbf 0 & 1 & \mathbf 1\\
\end{array}
$$
The next steps can only be (three times) one column, two rows (or the other way around). Is there a faster way?

What is the mathematical function, with wich we can make the whole array cells of $0$.
(My ideas are to first rearrange the columns and rows so that the numbers are in descending order from the top left corner (switching columns or rows is fine, since we can make the same steps from the original array)).

Comment: The title and the body of the question do not match.

Comment: I thought a lot about the title, and i couldn't think of a better one. Can you help me with a suggestion?

Comment: The body does not ask the same thing.

Comment: Is the question just for this array ?

Comment: No, any array of n times m and with any non negative integers inside it. This is just an example.

Comment: So when you ask "is there a faster way ?", faster way than what ? Your title and the body still disagree.

Comment: Is there a way with less steps? (One step is choosing the columns and the rows and substracting one from each cell)

Comment: Less steps than what ?

Comment: What are the least amount of steps?

Comment: Why don't you ask that in the question ?

Comment: That is the exact title.

Comment: Oh now i can understand what you are saying by the quastions dont match up.
Yes, the question is what are those but also how you get them.

Comment: And what do you mean by that "mathematical function" ?

Comment: What is the method to get those steps for any given array.

Answer (score 1):

For each step, you pick rows $r_1, \ldots, r_b$ and columns $c_1, \ldots, c_a$ and consider the outer product $E_{r, c} := (e_{r_1} + \cdots + e_{r_b})(e_{c_1} + \cdots + e_{c_a})^\top$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector. Now you want to express a given matrix $A$ in the form $\sum_{m=1}^N E_{r^{(m)}, c^{(m)}}$ for $N$ minimal.

The obvious thing to start with is to pick as many rows and columns as you can (that is, maximize $ab$), subtract them off, and do it again until you get to 0. That's a greedy algorithm. Even finding such a maximal set is [involved](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108299/given-a-large-binary-matrix-find-the-largest-submatrix-containing-non-zero-elem). These integer optimization problems are typically very hard to solve exactly efficiently.

Since your question and constraints are not particularly clear, I'll stop there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That is really helpful. The next question then is: is this the optimal way? Can i specify the questions which are unclear to you?

Comment: Well I strongly doubt this will be optimal. You should try some examples by hand yourself, usually counterexamples to optimality of the greedy algorithm aren't hard to find. A silly and completely impractical way to find the optimal value of $N$ is to simply brute-force it: there are only finitely many possible expressions. Most likely this is not an acceptable answer, but your question does not say what actual constraints you're facing and why the obvious brute-force is not a solution.

Comment: It's just a mathematical game, there is another way i can do this but i was thinking about what would be the best solution.
There are no constraints other than what i've already stated.